# Solve $\lfloor x^2 + 2x \rfloor = \lfloor x^2 \rfloor + 2 \lfloor x \rfloor$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How do we find all real $x$ such that $\lfloor x^2 + 2x \rfloor = \lfloor x^2 \rfloor + 2 \lfloor x \rfloor$, where $\lfloor \space \rfloor$ denotes the "greatest integer function" ?

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean $[1.2]=2$ and $[1.7]=2$? Or put in other words, what do you mean with "greatest integer function"?

Comment: No. [1,2]=1, [1,9]=1, [3.8]=3. If $n\leq x <n+1$ then $[x]=n$

Comment: The floor function is also known as the greatest integer function.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}
\floor{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_k}
\ge \floor{a_1} + \floor{a_2} + \cdots + \floor{a_k}
$$
with equality if and only if
$$
\{a_1\} + \{a_2\} + \cdots + \{a_k\}< 1
$$
where $\{ \space \}$ denotes the fractional part.
In particular,
$$
\floor{x^2 + 2x} \ge \floor{x^2} + \floor{x} + \floor{x}
$$
So if $\{x\} = r < 1, \{x^2\} = s < 1$, you are looking for when
$$
s + 2r < 1
$$
There are uncountably many solutions to this.
To generate a solution, take any irrational $r$ with $0 < r < \frac12$.
Then find any integer $n$ such that $2nr + r^2$
has fractional part less than $1 - 2r$, and let $x = n + r$.